# Loading HLSL shaders and multi-device directx 9 rendering

Tags: shader, gpu, hlsl, direct3d9

For a multi-device rendering setup using Shader Model 2.0:

1 LPDIRECT3D9 with 2 or more LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 objects.

Should I load/compile my shaders (HLSL) based on number of LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 objects.
Then provide each shader to its respective device object. 
Alternatively, is it expected to load/compile the shaders once and the GPU will provide the bytecode to each device auto-magically?

Comment: You have to provide the shaders to each device instance, and the driver may or may not have a shared internal cache to avoid the second-phase compile.

Comment: Thanks @ChuckWalbourn I'll take that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile HLSL to bytecode just once (even offline, as part of your build) because it doesn't depend on the underlying GPU architecture. However, at runtime you'll need to hold a set of IDirect3D???Shader9 objects for each device.